# Filter List by Array of Keywords & Sort by Best Match

Tags: javascript

I tried to implement a filtering logic by a list of keywords. If I write an exact keyword that an item already has the same name, it returns that one and a few more that has `new` and `hotel`.

I expect my logic to return the item whose name is `new hotel`, but it returns that one and 3 more. Then I thought I needed to sort the returned list by the best match so the item that has `new hotel` should be shown in the first index. How can I sort the returned list by the best match?

```js
const itemList = [{
    id: 23948,
    name: 'Arthouse Hotel New York'
  }, {
    id: 1231,
    name: 'Highgate Hotels new York Corperate Office'
  }, {
    id: 98237,
    name: 'new hotel'
  }, {
    id: 91829371,
    name: 'Smoke Gallery',
  },
  {
    id: 1123,
    name: 'Hotel Indigo Boston-Newton Riverside'
  }, {
    id: 919191,
    name: 'Pine Cay Hotel'
  }
];

const filterByValue = ['new', 'hotel'];


const nonIncludedItems = itemList.filter(property =>
  filterByValue.some(
    term => !property.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
  )
);
const includedItems = itemList.filter(property =>
  filterByValue.some(term =>
    property.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
  )
);

const result = includedItems.filter(i => !nonIncludedItems.includes(i));

console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: "best match" means exactly what? The one that the name is exaclty the same words that is in `filterByValue` array?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, what you're attempting to do is a fuzzy search. For that, look at [FuseJS](https://fusejs.io/)

A quick and dirty way would to just use something like [string-similarity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity)

It accepts a string to search for against an array of strings... so we could join your keywords into a single string, then search through an array of all your hotel names.

It will return an object consisting of the 'best match' and then the rest with their individual ratings. With this, you can simply sort the array from lowest to highest or vice versa on the ratings.

Check the docs on the link above for more information.

Stackoverflows snippet console isn't quite showing what it does in anyother playground like jsbin or codepen, so heres a screenshot of the response.

[image]

```js
const itemList = [{
    id: 23948,
    name: 'Arthouse Hotel New York'
  }, {
    id: 1231,
    name: 'Highgate Hotels new York Corperate Office'
  }, {
    id: 98237,
    name: 'new hotel'
  }, {
    id: 91829371,
    name: 'Smoke Gallery',
  },
  {
    id: 1123,
    name: 'Hotel Indigo Boston-Newton Riverside'
  }, {
    id: 919191,
    name: 'Pine Cay Hotel'
  }
];

const filterByValue = ['new', 'hotel'];

const names = itemList.map(hotel => hotel.name)
const bestMatch = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch(filterByValue.join(' '), names)

console.log(bestMatch)
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/string-similarity/umd/string-similarity.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to assign points based on the number of matches. Then filter the results that have zero matches and sort these that have one or more.

I used regular expressions but you can also use the word array, the code will get a little more complicated but the concept is the same.

```js
const itemList = [{
    id: 23948,
    name: 'Arthouse Hotel New York'
  }, {
    id: 1231,
    name: 'Highgate Hotels new York Corperate Office'
  }, {
    id: 98237,
    name: 'new hotel'
  }, {
    id: 91829371,
    name: 'Smoke Gallery',
  },
  {
    id: 1123,
    name: 'Hotel Indigo Boston-Newton Riverside'
  }, {
    id: 919191,
    name: 'Pine Cay Hotel'
  }
];



const countMatches = regex => registry => {
  const matches = registry.name.match(regex);
  
  if (matches && matches.length)
    registry.points = matches.length;
  else
    registry.points = 0;
  return registry;
};

const itemListwPoints = itemList.map(countMatches(/(new|hotel)/ig));

comparePoints = (a,b) => b.points - a.points; 

const nonIncludedItems = itemListwPoints.filter(property => property.points == 0);

const includedItems = itemListwPoints.filter(property => property.points > 0)
                        .sort(comparePoints);



console.log('included', includedItems);

console.log('nonIncluded', nonIncludedItems);
```